# Add Inline Styles In WP Dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I want to mimic the look of front-end in the WordPress dashboard. Since my Fonts are dynamic and user-changeable, I want to add inline styles. But the Post Editor Area is not accepting inline styles. Is there a solution to this.

Comment: When you say "in the WordPress dashboard", do you mean "in the post editor"?

Comment: Yes in the post editor. Also, I want to load Google fonts in the post editor.